# Keep a web app running in the background

Tags: javascript, websocket

I'm developing a web app using Intel XDK. The web app shall get receive data from a server. I want to keep the app running always in the background and connected to a server listening for messages. On receiving a message from the server, it shall send a notification. Can I even keep a web app running like that? If yes, how?

To be clear, I don't want to know how to get the data, but instead I want to know how to constantly keep it checking for data from server.

Comment: What does this have to do with HTML & CSS?

Comment: Paulie_D, consider editing the tags to improve the question next time.

Comment: Your question is way too broad. The answer is WebSockets if your browser and web server support it. If not, other techniques exist but some of them end up polling any way. The advantage is that all of this is transparent to you as a developer if you use a good library. I am not voting to close the question but I think that as it stands, doesn't fit into  SO format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Websockets or Socket.io library. You don't need keep checking new data from server, a server will tell you when a new data arrives

Comment: websocket connections do not remain open when the browser is in the background or the device is locked.